# how to change the value of data after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this problem to change the value of a variable that are using a loop that are triggered using button. For now my javascript code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cnt = 2;    
    $("#anc_add3").click(function() {
        $('#tbl4 tr').last().after('<tr><td><h3>PM [' + cnt + ']</h3></td><td><textarea> 
        cnt++;
    }); 

    var d = 2;
    $("#anc_addsupp").click(function() {
        $('#tbl4 tr:last-child').last().after('<tr><td><h3>Supplier [' + d + ']</h3></td><td>
        d++;
    });
```

What I am trying to do is to set a trigger that will restore `$cnt` initial value to `2` after clicking `#anc_addsupp`. Can anyone help me please I am struggling with this code for the past day.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code after `<textarea>`. It should be `<textarea>');`. What's the error anyway?

Comment: Can you provide us with this code in an example in jsfiddle, it would be useful for people to have it so they can test with your actual example.

Comment: Also do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: well, actually i combined my css code inside the textarea so the code was actually very very long. so i just provide the functionality to the data. no error was happening when i was running the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this.

```
var cnt = 2;   
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#anc_add3").click(function() {
            $('#tbl4 tr').last().after('<tr><td><h3>PM [' + cnt + ']</h3></td><td><textarea> 
            cnt++;
        }); 

        var d = 2;
        $("#anc_addsupp").click(function() {
            $('#tbl4 tr:last-child').last().after('<tr><td><h3>Supplier [' + d + ']</h3></td><td>
            d++;
           cnt = 2;
        });
});
```